# Getting ErrImagePull : 401 Unauthorized when creating a Kubernetes Pod with a declarative command

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud

I am working through a lab that shows how to set-up Kubernetes and the CLI on IBM Cloud.

I have the Kubernetes cluster setup, and the container registry. I am logged in to IBM Cloud and the Container Registry on the CLI. The image has been created and pushed.

I can create a pod using the image with an imperative command using:

```
kubectl create -f hello-world-create.yaml
```

where the `yaml` file looks like:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  containers:
  - name: hello-world
    image: us.icr.io/earlyprogramimages/hello-world:1
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: icr
```

but when I try the declarative command for the same image running

```
kubectl apply -f hello-world-apply.yaml
```

where the `yaml` file looks like

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  generation: 1
  labels:
    run: hello-world
  name: hello-world
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: hello-world
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: hello-world
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: us.icr.io/earlyprogramimages/hello-world:1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: hello-world
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: icr
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

I get status of `ErrImagePull` for each of the pods where the event stack is

```
Successfully assigned default/hello-world-6fd8bd67dc-79gbz to xx.xx.xx.xx
Pulling image "us.icr.io/earlyprogramimages/hello-world:1

Failed to pull image "us.icr.io/earlyprogramimages/hello-world:1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "us.icr.io/earlyprogramimages/hello-world:1": failed to resolve reference "us.icr.io/earlyprogramimages/hello-world:1": failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized

Error: ErrImagePull
```

Clearly the command doesn't have read access to image, but I have logged in successfully using

```
ibmcloud cr login
```

and can deploy a pod using the imperative create command.

I have been through the documentation, but can't determine which step I have overlooked. What are the extra steps needed which grant the appropriate access for the declarative apply command?

Running

```
kubectl get secrets -n default | grep "icr-io"
```

gives

```
kubectl get secrets -n default | grep "icr-io"
all-icr-io            kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson        1      167m
default-au-icr-io     kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson        1      167m
default-de-icr-io     kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson        1      167m
default-icr-io        kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson        1      167m
default-jp-icr-io     kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson        1      167m
default-uk-icr-io     kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson        1      167m
default-us-icr-io     kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson        1      167m
```

Comment: Have you tried doing docker pull to pull the image?

Comment: docker pull of the image works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I did and worked as expected,

As you can see `all-icr-io` is the default image pull secret provided in your cluster. *Not sure why you were using `icr`*

> By default, the IBM Cloud Kubernetes cluster is set up to pull images
> from only your account’s namespace in IBM Cloud Container Registry by
> using the secret `all-icr-io` in the default namespace.

Check the [documentation here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-registry#other) to copy the existing image pull secret to a non-default namespace

So, my `hello-world-create` looks like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  containers:
  - name: hello-world
    image: us.icr.io/mods15/hello-world:1
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: all-icr-io
```

and my `hello-world-apply.yaml` is

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  generation: 1
  labels:
    run: hello-world
  name: hello-world
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: hello-world
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: hello-world
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: us.icr.io/mods15/hello-world:1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: hello-world
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: all-icr-io
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

Here's the outcome once the `yaml` files are configured successfully
[image]

Comment: Thanks, changing  `imagePullSecrets` `name` to `all-icr-io` did the trick.

Comment: How do you make your kubectl output formatted like that? is this a plugin?

Comment: @YacineLazaar The tool is https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kui

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-registry#cluster_registry_auth for details on what might be wrong.. Some things to check:

1. Do you have IAM policies in place that grant you access to the container registry?
2. Does `kubectl get secrets -n default | grep "icr-io"` show any pull secrets? If not, follow that doc link above to fix it.

Comment: I have updated the question with the output from the command. I am checking the documentation link you provided for clues.

Comment: Found something related to when clusters were created. My Kubernetes cluster is new, but my registry namespace is quite old. I think I will drop and recreate the namespace.

Comment: Created a brand new cluster and brand new registry namespace - same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well but on Azure. I tried everything but nothing helped or was already configured that way. What worked for me was to downgrade my Linux version. After a lot of digging I found that Azure Kubernetes Service runs on 16 and 18 so I chose one of those builds and it worked.